# How can I direct html2pdf which stylesheet to use without affecting the page?

Tags: javascript, css, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm using the library [Html2Pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js) which works really well to allow my app's users to download as PDF their invoices displayed in HTML. The problem encountered is when anyone needs to download his/her invoice while using dark mode.

Switching from light to dark mode and reverse works by adding/removing a "disabled" attribute to the link tag:

```
<link href="path/to/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="light" />
<link href="path/to/css/app-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="dark" disabled="disabled" />
```

Both files have the same css rules, only colours change.

If someone is using dark mode and need to download a PDF, html2pdf.js will print it exactly as it shown based on current css rules, therefore with black/gray backgrounds/fonts which isn't really ideal for an invoice!

I already tried to change styles dynamically in the function which render the PDF after click, but of course the change is clearly visible to the user since it affects the whole page (app page meaned here).

Therefore, my question is the following : How could I tell the function html2pdf() which CSS rules using without affecting the page itself?

**EDIT**

Since there's objectively no real solution this is what I did (and not proud of) :

I duplicated the whole element which was use for PDF printing to a second version hide from the user (display: none;) with its own styling on each concerned  and other elements.

Therefore this version stays white-based and the "display: none" styling property doesn't affect how html2pdf get the element to create a PDF based on.

This is the only solution I found for now but I would of course be pleased if someone comes with a proper one !

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need dar mode in pdf?
Almost every pdf reader has the ability to switch to dark mode by itself, even an ordinary adobe reader.

Comment: You don't get it, I don't want a pdf in dark mode but the opposite.

To recap :
My application is a Saas dashboard with both "regular" and "dark mode". There is a page "invoice" where any invoice is displayed in HTML and of course in dark mode the document show a dark based invoice so when I render it to PDF with html2pdf it give me a dark based pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the *toContainer()* function to resolve the issue.

Like so:

```
html2pdf().set(opt).from(itinerary).toContainer().save();
```

When you do so, [Html2Pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js) wraps your content in a div with this class:
*html2pdf__container*

You can then transform your styles via the css.

I went digging into the source code to find this:
https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/blob/master/src/worker.js
*(lines 97 to 128)*

Note: You'll want to be mindful that [Html2Pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js) also applies an inline style to the container. So if you want to override any of the following, you'll have to use *!important*

```
/* inline styles (lines 111 to 115) */
var containerCSS = {
  position: 'absolute', width: this.prop.pageSize.inner.width + this.prop.pageSize.unit,
  left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, height: 'auto', margin: 'auto',
  backgroundColor: 'white'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can paste style to head or even a styles file. It doesn't work here, but check out [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/Tomik23/pen/mdBPxVN)

If you do not need to support old browsers, you can use the css variables and, for example, after clicking, change the parameters by
`document.documentElement.style.setProperty("-color", "#000");`

I know this does not solve the problem, but a change to the html2pdf itself seems very hard to obtain.

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".makePDF");

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const style = document.createElement("style");
  style.textContent = `body { background: #fff; color: #000; }`;
  document.head.appendChild(style);

  const element = document.querySelector("body");
  const opt = {
    margin: 1,
    filename: "myfile.pdf",
    image: {
      type: "jpeg",
      quality: 0.98
    },
    html2canvas: {
      scale: 1
    },
    jsPDF: {
      unit: "mm",
      orientation: "landscape",
    },
  };

  html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: nhg-text-bold, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -0.4px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.border {
  height: 400px;
  width: 890px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.verLogo {
  padding-left: 400px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.mainContent h1 {
  margin-left: 280px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.sepLine {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

.UserName,
h2,
h3 {
  margin-left: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-GsLlZN/3F2ErC5ifS5QtgpiJtWd43JWSuIgh7mbzZ8zBps+dvLusV+eNQATqgA/HdeKFVgA5v3S/cIrLF7QnIg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<button type="button" class="makePDF">PDF</button>
<div id="content">
  <div class="border">
    <div class="mainContent">
      <h1>CONGRATULATIONS</h1>
      <div class="sepLine"></div>
      <span class="UserName">
            <h2>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</h2>
            <h3>You have completed</h3>
            <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h1>
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm still facing the issue where change apply to the whole page and therefore the end user.

Answer (score -3):

Place the appropriate color overrides in a `@media print` block, and *always* include that CSS on the page. For example,

```html
<style>
@media print {
  body {
    background-color: white !important;
    color: black !important;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it is not working since it seems that html2pdf.js does not use the regular "print" function to create the PDF.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be a long-standing [known issue](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+print+media) with that library. Someone posted a [work-around](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues/79#issuecomment-367082643), but I'm sure its effect will be visible.

Comment: Indeed, the process is quite similar to what I tried, the invoice going back to a white based version and then switch back to dark based. Sad there's no "hided" solution ..